# Changing the Format of an In-text Citation

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using \cite{} with a bst file and it is generating Harvard references in the text as follows:

Qiao et al. (2013)

instead I would like the reference to appear as:

(Qiao et al., 2013)

Any ideas how I can do this??

Comment: are you using `natbib`? Then you could do `\citep{...}`

Comment: See http://merkel.texture.rocks/Latex/natbib.php for a good overview of using `natbib`.